# image slider on Tab Selection in Android

Tags: android

i want to implement image slider on tab selection in android without using fragment .Already i have created 2 view pager one is home information and another second is only images.Right now i want to show tab and view pager only in single activity.I have create two tabs in activity but i don't understand how to show view pager on first tab selection and slide to the pages  for showing information and when i select the second tab show the image view pager and slide the images.Can someone help how to do this.Thanks to appreciates.

Comment: your question's like, there's A and B, A has C and shows D, B has D but doesn't want to show C.. It's confusing, ask only single thing at a time and also post relevant code

Comment: No , Actually select Tab 'A' I want to display ViewPager_Home for slide the pages  when  , when selelct Tab 'B' then display the ViewPager_Imagen for slide the all images on one Activity.